# Android ScrollView with heavy layout Memory issue

Tags: android, performance

In my app, I made a list view in MainActvity it opens 12 fragment. To open them I used `fragmentTransaction.replace`. Every fragment has swipe tabs with 3 fragment. In one of them I used two scroll view. I divide the screen
left and right side.Like this  [ scroll view |  scroll view ]

I wrote every codes in layout file. (Java files are empty I don't know what to write).
Here what scroll views have. (There are 20 items in it)

```
  <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:isScrollContainer="false"
    android:layout_weight="1">
   <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
      <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
           <ImageView
                android:layout_width="400dp"
                android:layout_height="400dp"
                android:src="@drawable/akrep_ahmet_kural"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="210dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/burc_akrep"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="Ahmet Kural"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="210dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/burc_akrep"
                android:text="10 Kasım 1982"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />
      </LinearLayout>
  <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="400dp"
                android:layout_height="400dp"
                android:src="@drawable/akrep_alp_kirsan" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="210dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/burc_akrep"
                .
                .
                .
```

The problem is when user click the scroll view tab it comes slowly but scrolling has no lags. Then the user go back memory usage stay the same. Then user open another scroll view tab, memory usage increse again and it becomes like stairs. After that force close comes.

So what to do?

Answer (score 0):

You should use either `Listview` or `RecyclerView` as it wont load all the views at the beginning but only what are visible plus one or two more which will be quite less resource-intensive than your approach.

Comment: I changed them to listviews (actually i wrote with list view for the first time )but when i install the app to old phones and scroll fast app get force close. I have searched to make list view smooth but coundt find anything(actuallly i found a lot but non of them worked).Now i made listviews with setFriction(ViewConfiguration.getScrollFriction() * 10);  so app doesnt get force but scrolling is not fun :) Do you know any document for making a smooth scroll list view from the beginning to end (or can you write) i am new about this. Thanks :D

Comment: The reason for force close could be that when you scroll fast, android is not able to remove the previous bitmap and tries to load new one which causes it to crash. I would recommend using library like picasso or fresco to handle images.

Answer (score 0):

It does look like you should be using a ListView and an adapter.

Please also note that "wrap_content" is quite unhelpful for efficiency as changes to the width (for example, setting the text in a TextView with width set to "wrap_content") can cause the entire view to be re-drawn, slowing down the application.